# Forgot to add one year old child's details while booking an Indian Railways ticket

Tags: indian-railways, age-limits, irctc

I had booked a ticket for travel through Indian Railways using IRCTC and got a confirmed ticket. While booking, I forgot to mention the details of a one year old child who will also be traveling.

Will it create any problem while boarding the train?

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking if there is going to be some sort of problem? How to update the information to include the child's details? Something else?

Comment: Although it'll probably be obvious, it may be worth holding onto some proof of age for the child just in case.

Answer (score 11):

Traveling with less than 5 years child with out mentioning their details in the ticket in Indian Railways is not a problem.

In your case for a one year child, the Train Ticket Examiner (TTE) won't ask any details. In my experience, you can tell the truth to TTE they won't make any issue.

The ticket fare applicable for more than 5 years old children only.

Comment: +1. The [child fare change notification](http://pib.nic.in/newsite/PrintRelease.aspx?relid=132573) says that children under 5 continue to be carried free of charge. Therefore, the names of such children are not reflected on the ticket.

Answer (score 8):

The other answer is perfectly correct, travelling with one or even more children of age 5 and below is not a problem, the reason I am adding another answer is just so that everyone visiting in future understand the full implications.

The details of Children travelling together with adults is taken for use in emergency alone.  In case if there is an emergency and god forbid the child is left alone, this information is used to track them and hence in future please make sure this information is provided.

Comment: In a case of a train accident, for insurance claim / govt benefit on record name is must.

Comment: @skv Can I add the names after booking?

Comment: @TIGER this cannot be done online, I am not aware of the current procedure offline, but it is generally not possible in the centres too, they may ask you to buy an additional ticket stating the age as 5+